# Cocoa How to Set a Radio button state without using Matrix

Tags: macos, cocoa, radio-button

Without using matrix how do I set a button's state?!  It used to be very easy with matrix but now in 10.8 and the depreciation of matrix I'm not sure how to set a radio button's state when the window is loaded.

Here I check to see is a variable (p.status) is set to "Pending" and if so, I want the radio button (linked to "pending" in IB) to have its state set to "1"

Driving me nuts!!!

In my .h

```
 IBOutlet NSButton *pending;
```

In my .m

```
if([p.status isEqualToString:@"Pending"]){
   //pending.state  = 1; Doesn't work
   //[NSButtonCell:pending [setstate:NSOnState]]; Doesn't work
   //[(NSButtonCell *)pending.cell setstate(ON)]; Doesn't work
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked for me.  I created unique identifiers for each radio button in IB>Identity Inspector ("pendingButton" approvedButton" rejectedButton") removed the bindings from the radio buttons to the IBOutlet NSButton in the header file. And implemented this code:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)table_view viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {  
    Proposal *p = [list objectAtIndex:row];  
    NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];  
    NSString *holdingValue;  

    NSTableCellView *cell = [table_view makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:self];  
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"status"]){  
        if(p){  
            for (NSView *subview in cell.subviews) {  
                if (![subview isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]]) continue;  

                if ([subview.identifier isEqualToString:@"pendingButton"])  
                    [(NSButton *)subview setState:[p.status isEqualToString: @"Pending"] ? NSOnState : NSOffState];  
                else if ([subview.identifier isEqualToString:@"approvedButton"])  
                    [(NSButton *)subview setState:[p.status isEqualToString: @"Approved"] ? NSOnState : NSOffState];  
                else if ([subview.identifier isEqualToString:@"rejectedButton"])  
                    [(NSButton *)subview setState:[p.status isEqualToString: @"Rejected"] ? NSOnState : NSOffState];  
            }  
        }  
    }else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"clientAccessPoint"]){  
        holdingValue = [p valueForKey:identifier];  
            if (!holdingValue){  
                cell.textField.stringValue = @"N/A";  
            }else{  
                cell.textField.stringValue = [p valueForKey:identifier];  
            }  
    }else{  
    cell.textField.stringValue = [p valueForKey:identifier];  
    }  
    return cell;  
}
```